# Javascript - How to Escape Double quotes from Dynamic string content, Unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Have used to Bind Login User name from portal to a Javascript variable. User name contains either SingleQuote or DiubleQuote sometimes.

My Javascript code failed to read string with DiubleQuote.

EX:

```
var userName = "Happy and "Care" Ltd"; -  error: unknown: Unexpected token, expected ";"
var userName1 = 'Happy and Care's Ltd'; - error: unknown: Unexpected token, expected ";"
```

Comment: That's part of any JS tutorial and should be easily solvable by a quick search with your preferred search provider (Google, Bing, Yahoo, ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use backticks `` like this :

```js
var userName = `Happy and "Care" Ltd`;
var userName1 = `Happy and Care's Ltd`;

console.log(userName)
console.log(userName1)
```

[More reading about template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Hello Namysh - Backtick is working only in Chrome, Edge and Firefox. the same is not supported in IE11 version. stucked again.

Comment: Backtick is working only in Chrome, Edge and Firefox. the same is not supported in IE11 version. any suggestions?

Comment: Considering the binding is dynamic you don't need to write anything then don't need any escaping no ?

Comment: yeah its Dynamic binding. when username comes like "john's garage"(single quote inbetween name) its working fine. the same is failed when username comes like "Peter "st" paul"(double quote inbetween name). when a user name contains a double quote that name becomes unreadable by js code.

Comment: Ok and how you the binding is applied ? Are you using some front-end framework ?

Comment: No front-end involved. simply binding  `var loginUserName = "<%AppSecurity.LoggedinUser.Name.FullName%>";`

Comment: Are you using ASP.net or something like this ? What is the <% %> syntax

Comment: am using MVC. this code comes under a JS script like
 `var loginUserName = "<%AppSecurity.LoggedinUser.Name.FullName%>";`

Comment: Ok but how it works, basically some unknow technology remplace <%AppSecurity.LoggedinUser.Name.FullName%> with the user's fullname and then the javascript code is run?

Comment: here am just binding login user name to JS variable from Base config settings.my current code is giving result like `var loginUserName =  "john's garage"` - working fine one more user like `var loginUserName = "Peter "st" paul" ` - breaking (Invalid charecter error inIE11). so expecting js to read the value with both ' and " as well.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is used as a escape character. For example you can use like this:

```
var userName1 = 'Happy and Care\'s Ltd';
```

Comment: Not able to add any escape character as the Text am getting is a Dynamic binding one. sample text will be 1. "All here "IS" Well", 2. "This is User's name"

Answer (score 1):

Found Solution Finally...

```js
var userName = /"John "Deo" Peter"/;  
var resulrtStr = userName.toString().replace(/\\|\//g,'').replace(/['"]+/g, '');
```

Hope this would help someone someday!...